# Android device's log file

Tags: android, device, logfile-analysis

using logcat I can see the log messages generated by my app in the emulator. How can I read/retrieve the same log file but this time from the device the app is running on ? The device is not attached to any computer and the log file has to be sent via email.

Answer (score 3):

To read the log from within your application you need to have the android.permission.READ_LOGS permission.

Once you have that, you could start up a process to read logcat with something like

```
Process logcatProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat");
```

Then you can create a buffered reader from it:

```
BufferedReader logcat = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(logcatProcess.getInputStream()), 8192);
```

From here you can `String s = logcat.readLine();` to read the log.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [log collector project](http://code.google.com/p/android-log-collector/) that you can use from your code/application. If you want an already existing application, try [Log Collector](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.xtralogic.android.logcollector).

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this app on the market](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.xtralogic.android.logcollector&feature=search_result).  It does what you need and it is open source!